# EF How to update related table value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Scenario**

I have 2 tables, person and their activities, every time I create an activity I also have to select a person to which belongs that activity. now how do I save/always update the ***LatestActivityId** record of the person *personId*?

this is because I would like to track what was the person's last activity data.

many thanks for your input

Here is what I have so far:

```
    [HttpPost]

   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId" + "," + "ActivityTypeId")] dbo_Activities dbo_Activities)

   {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {

     // >>STUCK HERE<< //int SaveAsLatestActivity = db.dbo_Businesses.Max(p => p.ActivityId);

     db.dbo_Activities.Add(dbo_Activities);

     db.SaveChanges();

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // ComboBox >> selects person

    ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(db.dbo_Businesses, "PersonId", "FullName", dbo_Activities.PersonId);

    return View(dbo_Activities);
   }
```

My Activity Model

```
 public class dbo_Activities
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Activity Id")]
        public Int32 ActivityId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Person Id")]
        public Int32? PersonId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you show your Activities model please.

Comment: you have the `PersonId` so after you create the activity and it gets an id, query the person out of the persons table, set the `LatestActivityId` to the id of the activity you just created and save the person

Comment: @AntonToshik Thanks for being here, I have added my activity model in the question

Comment: @GregH Thanks for being here.. could you please explain what you mean?

Comment: @Yosh take a look at my answer and see if that's what you're going for. Let me know if anything doesn't make sense to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `PersonId` so after you create the activity and it gets an id, query the person out of the persons table, set the `LatestActivityId` to the id of the activity you just created and save the person. You haven't posted your full models so I'm making some assumptions about what certain properties are called and the name of models but it should look something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PersonId" + "," + "ActivityTypeId")] dbo_Activities dbo_Activities)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.dbo_Activities.Add(dbo_Activities);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //set LatestActivityId on the person to the ActivityId of the entry that was just created
        var person = db.dbo_Persons.Single(x => x.Id == dbo_Activities.PersonId);
        person.LatestActivityId = dbo_Activities.ActivityId;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewData["PersonId"] = new SelectList(db.dbo_Businesses, "PersonId", "FullName", dbo_Activities.PersonId);

    return View(dbo_Activities);
}
```

Comment: Awesome it worked! I hope this helps someone else in the future!